# Indexed URLs in Google Webmaster Tools are missing after migrating to another framework

Tags: google-search-console, google-index, xml-sitemap

I migrated my site last week from an old `.aspx` framework to a new site hosted via WordPress.

The domain name is the same and I am seeing no errors when I test and submit the sitemap via Google Webmaster Tools. However, Google Webmaster Tools is showing that my indexed URLs dropped to ZERO the day after the switch, and it has not yet picked back up (the blue bar graph is listed at 448 URLs, there is no longer a red bar graph).

I still see my URLs in the SERPs, but much lower than before the move, and so a lot less Google traffic. How can I know for sure if something is going wrong? I can't seem to find anything to support this matter.

Comment: Did your url structure change?

Comment: Yes it did, but I've put in place the proper 301 redirects to handle the changes.

Comment: It might take Google some time to completely discover and index your new URL's. I suffered traffic loss for about 3 months after I changed my URL structure...

Comment: That sounds terrible! How many URLs did you have that migrated over to a new structure? So I shouldn't be concerned that my indexed URLS went from ~400 to zero overnight?

Comment: I had about 7k URL's. The bar you decribe is not the total number of URL's that are indexed by the way, just the number of URL's that were indexed *from that sitemap*. you changed the sitemap so it's normal that that dropped to 0. Google Index > Index Status will still have a decent number indexed and if you Google site:mysite.com, there will still be a lot of indexed pages.

Comment: That actually helps a lot -- because I was seeing varying data within GWT on how many URLs were indexed. THanks for the explanation.

Comment: @IvoVdv Maybe you should copy your comments into an answer?

Answer (score 2):

The bar you decribe is not the total number of URL's that are indexed, just the number of URL's that were indexed from that sitemap. you changed the sitemap so it's normal that that dropped to 0. Google Index > Index Status will still have a decent number indexed and if you Google site:mysite.com, there will still be a lot of indexed pages.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the red bar in Google Webmaster Tools show up again when I fixed these two things:

1. I had the sitemap listed twice in the *robots.txt* file. I was using a robots plug-in and All-in one SEO plug-in which appended the sitemap link at the bottom of the *robots.txt* file.  Look at your *robots.txt* file by going to `http://www.yourdomain.com/robots.txt` and seeing if you've got a similar problem.
2. I had 1,800 warnings from Google from the sitemap.  I looked at the examples and saw that my sitemap was serving files I was telling *robots.txt* to block.  I re-configured my sitemap plug-in not list those files to begin with. I'm not down to zero errors yet, but nearly so.